# Кодировка для БД

Tags: кодировка, база-данных, utf-8, mysql

Создаю базу данных, в которой будут содержаться данные о студентах (буквы кириллицей). Кодировку лучше выбрать для бд в этом случае?
Пользуюсь dbforge, хоть это и не важно.

Пока остановился на utf-8.

Answer (score 2):

Жизнь будет проще, если везде, и в бд и на сайте (или где это будет выводиться) будет UTF-8